# PyQt5 QLabel setWordWrap doesn't work when labels text contains only letters

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, pyqt5, qlabel

So, I am trying to make a whatsapp like app that allow you to chat with someone and works thru using firebase but the thing is message qlabel doesnt work properly. qLabels text is forcing ScrollArea to expand horizontally instead of making itself vetrically bigger. When the text of Qlabel contains spaces between words, setwordwrap works perfectly otherwise it's not working the way I want. I ll share pics of ui below.

With spaces its fine:

[image: with spaces its fine]

And the problem:

[image: and the problem]

and I'm adding this message widgets dynamicly from code:

```
    msgContent = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    msgConLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    userIconWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    userIconWidLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    msgWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    msgWidLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    icon = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    message = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    date = QtWidgets.QLabel()

    msgWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue; border-radius: 10px; background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35);")
    icon.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 25px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(44, 49, 60); border: 5px solid rgb(39, 44, 54);")
    message.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;")
    date.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;")

    icon.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sagoe UI", 16))
    message.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sagoe UI", 10))
    date.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sagoe UI", 10))

    icon.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    icon.setText("R")
    message.setText(self.ui.ChatInput.text())
    message.setWordWrap(True)
    message.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextInteractionFlag.TextSelectableByMouse)
    current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
    time = current_time.toString("hh:mm")
    date.setText(time)

    userIconWidget.setMaximumWidth(50)
    userIconWidget.setMinimumWidth(50)
    icon.setMinimumSize(50,50)
    icon.setMaximumSize(50,50)
    msgContent.setMinimumHeight(80)
    date.setMaximumHeight(25)
    date.setMinimumHeight(25)

    msgWidLayout.setSpacing(0)
    msgWidLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    userIconWidLayout.setSpacing(0)
    userIconWidLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    userIconWidLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
    msgConLayout.setSpacing(10)
    msgConLayout.setContentsMargins(150,0,0,0)

    userIconWidLayout.addWidget(icon)
    msgWidLayout.addWidget(message)
    msgWidLayout.addWidget(date)
    userIconWidget.setLayout(userIconWidLayout)
    msgWidget.setLayout(msgWidLayout)
    msgConLayout.addStretch()
    msgConLayout.addWidget(msgWidget)
    msgConLayout.addWidget(userIconWidget)
    msgContent.setLayout(msgConLayout)
    self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.layout().addWidget(msgContent)
    self.ui.ChatInput.setText("")
```

and what I trying to add:

[image: widgets]
[image]

I tried to make maximum width of label 300 and this happend:

This time I cant see the whole text:

[image: this time I cant see the whole text]

```
    message.setMaximumWidth(300)
```

Comment: QLabel only supports basic word wrap (using standard separators like spaces or punctuation), and it also doesn't work well with layout management when wrapping is active. If you want a "word wrap anywhere" you need to use a full QTextDocument capable widget (like QTextEdit) or a custom widget that implements it, so that you're able of using QTextOption's [`setWrapMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextoption.html#setWrapMode).

Comment: Ok, I ll try to replace qlabels with qtextedits

Comment: Note that in order to properly use QTextEdit you have to ensure that they are always displayed at the full extent of their contents, otherwise you'll have a nested scroll area (which you probably don't want). In any case, in order to achieve what you want, you must take your time to learn much more about the whole QTextDocument interface and its structure. It's not rocket science, but don't expect to get it in a couple of days, as text layout management requires *a lot* of experience. There are some similar posts on the same topic even here on SO, I suggest you to do some thorough research.

Comment: I created a new qmainwindow which only have qtextedit. I tried 'setWordWrapMode(QtGui.QTextOption.WrapAnywhere)', text wrapped but qtextedit still have the same size. It didnt adjust its size.

Comment: As said above, *you* have to ensure that they are always displayed at the full extent of their contents. QTextEdit is a scroll area, it's point is *exactly* to not require resizing when the contents change; if you need to vertically adapt the widget, you have to do it programmatically, possibly by connecting to the signals of QTextEdit or its underlying QTextDocument.